# How do I speed up finding shortest path with unique combinations of the 2 dimensions?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Long story short, I'm making a search box that has an array representing the distance between the search words and the words in the results. After these distances are calculated, I have a data structure like `dataset` below. The first dimension represents what resultWord I'm dealing with whereas the index on the second dimension represents what searchWord I'm dealing with.

The Goal: Only match a search word to a result word once. If a result word was used as a match already, it cannot be reused. And the resulting path should be the one in which the distance when added up between all the combinations is the lowest.

After I type about three search words, Chrome starts to freeze up. Chrome's profiler says it's definitely coming from `getBestDistancePath`. And I don't understand why, it's only comparing integers. It's not like it's doing string manipulation or anything.

Is there anyway to speed this up with caching or a completely different way to go about it that would be faster?

If I entered "m g" into the search box this is basically what it would translate into for the row that had a column "Medical: Gastrointestinal Assessment":

```js
var dataset = [  
  [  
    {  
      "distance":7,
      "searchWord":"m",
      "resultWord":"medical:"
    },
    {  
      "distance":8,
      "searchWord":"g",
      "resultWord":"medical:"
    }
  ],
  [  
    {  
      "distance":16,
      "searchWord":"m",
      "resultWord":"gastrointestinal"
    },
    {  
      "distance":15,
      "searchWord":"g",
      "resultWord":"gastrointestinal"
    }
  ],
  [  
    {  
      "distance":9,
      "searchWord":"m",
      "resultWord":"assessment"
    },
    {  
      "distance":10,
      "searchWord":"g",
      "resultWord":"assessment"
    }
  ]
];

// Find best unique searchWord to resultWord match up for lowest edit distance
let path = getBestDistancePath(dataset, []);

// Convert path into more usable representation
let result = path.map(point => {
 return dataset[point[0]][point[1]];
});

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);


function didUseIndex(path, index, value) {
 for (var ii = 0; ii < path.length; ii++) {
  if (path[ii][index] === value) {
   return true;
  }
 }

 return false;
}

function getBestDistancePath(distances, currentPath) {
 let distanceLen = distances.length;
 if (distanceLen === 0)
  return currentPath;

 // Only need the best combos for the amount of search words that exist
 let searchWordLen = distances[0].length;
 if (currentPath.length == searchWordLen)
  return currentPath;

 let min      = Infinity;
 let bestPath = currentPath;

 for (let i = 0; i < distanceLen; i++) {
  // i tells me what resultWord is being used
  if (didUseIndex(currentPath, 0, i)) {
   continue;
  }

  for (let j = 0; j < searchWordLen; j++) {
   // j tells me what searchWord is being used
   if (didUseIndex(currentPath, 1, j)) {
    // If this version has been used in this trial, skip it
    continue;
   }

   // Concat creates new array so it isn't shared memory
   let path = getBestDistancePath(distances, currentPath.concat([ [i, j] ]));

   // Add up all the distances in the path
   let totalDistance = 0;
   for (let k = 0, len3 = path.length; k < len3; k++) {
    let curr = path[k];
    totalDistance += distances[curr[0]][curr[1]].distance;
   }

   if (totalDistance < min) {
    min = totalDistance;
    bestPath = path;
   }
  }
 }

 return bestPath;
}
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: So by "only comparing integers" you actually mean "only comparing integers inside three nested loops, and it recurses too"?